# change the login which originally used the email, password, role_id from the users table to use the UserID, password, level from the Visuser table?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-9

I want to change the authentication, which initially uses data from the users table (default), to use the visuser table.

When I try to log in, no error messages appear, but only endless loading.

[loading while login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6GG9.png)

[users table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhRQ5.png)

[visuser table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIGES.png)

[visuser table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NuNjb.png)

I've tried changing some of the code from the files App\Http\Controllers\AuthController, resources\views\auth\login.blade.php, config\auth.php, app\Models\Visuser.php, app\Models\User.php, app\Http\Requests\LoginRequests\LoginRequest.php. I expect it will go to the specified page. In fact, it even loads endlessly.

routes\web.php

```
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\AttendanceController;
use App\Http\Controllers\AuthController;
use App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController;
use App\Http\Controllers\EmployeeController;
use App\Http\Controllers\HolidayController;
use App\Http\Controllers\HomeController;
use App\Http\Controllers\PositionController;
use App\Http\Controllers\PresenceController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use SebastianBergmann\CodeCoverage\Report\Html\Dashboard;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/


Route::middleware('auth')->group(function () {
    Route::middleware('role:admin,operator')->group(function () {
        // Route::get('/dashboard', [DashboardController::class, 'index'])->name('dashboard.index');
        // positions
        Route::resource('/positions', PositionController::class)->only(['index', 'create']);
        Route::get('/positions/edit', [PositionController::class, 'edit'])->name('positions.edit');
        // employees
        Route::resource('/employees', EmployeeController::class)->only(['index', 'create']);
        Route::get('/employees/edit', [EmployeeController::class, 'edit'])->name('employees.edit');
        // holidays (hari libur)
        Route::resource('/holidays', HolidayController::class)->only(['index', 'create']);
        Route::get('/holidays/edit', [HolidayController::class, 'edit'])->name('holidays.edit');
        // attendances (absensi)
        Route::resource('/attendances', AttendanceController::class)->only(['index', 'create']);

        Route::get('/attendances/edit', [AttendanceController::class, 'edit'])->name('attendances.edit');

        // presences (kehadiran)
        Route::resource('/presences', PresenceController::class)->only(['index']);
        // Route::get('/presences/qrcode', [PresenceController::class, 'showQrcode'])->name('presences.qrcode');
        Route::get('/presences/qrcode/{attendance}', [PresenceController::class, 'showQrcode'])->name('presences.qrcode');
        Route::get('/presences/qrcode/download-pdf', [PresenceController::class, 'downloadQrCodePDF'])->name('presences.qrcode.download-pdf');
        Route::get('/presences/{attendance}', [PresenceController::class, 'show'])->name('presences.show');
        // not present data
        Route::get('/presences/{attendance}/not-present', [PresenceController::class, 'notPresent'])->name('presences.not-present');
        Route::post('/presences/{attendance}/not-present', [PresenceController::class, 'notPresent']);
        // present (url untuk menambahkan/mengubah user yang tidak hadir menjadi hadir)
        Route::post('/presences/{attendance}/present', [PresenceController::class, 'presentUser'])->name('presences.present');
        Route::post('/presences/{attendance}/acceptPermission', [PresenceController::class, 'acceptPermission'])->name('presences.acceptPermission');
        // employees permissions

        Route::get('/presences/{attendance}/permissions', [PresenceController::class, 'permissions'])->name('presences.permissions');
    });

    Route::middleware('role:user')->name('home.')->group(function () {
        Route::get('/', [HomeController::class, 'start'])->name('index');
        Route::get('/home', [HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
        // desctination after scan qrcode
        Route::post('/absensi/qrcode', [HomeController::class, 'sendEnterPresenceUsingQRCode'])->name('sendEnterPresenceUsingQRCode');
        Route::post('/absensi/qrcode/out', [HomeController::class, 'sendOutPresenceUsingQRCode'])->name('sendOutPresenceUsingQRCode');

        Route::get('/absensi/{attendance}', [HomeController::class, 'show'])->name('show');
        Route::get('/absensi/{attendance}/permission', [HomeController::class, 'permission'])->name('permission');
    });

    Route::delete('/logout', [AuthController::class, 'logout'])->name('auth.logout');
});

Route::middleware('guest')->group(function () {
    // auth
    Route::get('/login', [AuthController::class, 'index'])->name('auth.login');
    Route::post('/login', [AuthController::class, 'authenticate']);
});
```

App\Http\Controllers\AuthController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests\LoginRequests\LoginRequest;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('auth.login', [
            "title" => "Masuk"
        ]);
    }

    public function username()
    {
        return 'UserID'; // this string is column of accounts table which we are going use for login
    }

    public function authenticate(LoginRequest $request)
    {
        // $remember = $request->boolean('remember');
        $credentials = $request->only(['UserID', 'password']);

        if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) { // login gagal
            request()->session()->regenerate();
            $data = [
                "success" => true,
                // "redirect_to" => auth()->user()->isUser() ? route('home.index') : route('dashboard.index'),
                "redirect_to" => auth()->user()->isUser() ? route('home.index') : route('attendances.index'),
                "message" => "Login berhasil, silahkan tunggu!"
            ];
            return response()->json($data);
        }

        $data = [
            "success" => false,
            "message" => "Login gagal, silahkan coba lagi!"
        ];
        return response()->json($data)->setStatusCode(400);
    }

    public function logout()
    {
        auth()->logout();

        request()->session()->regenerate();
        request()->session()->regenerateToken();

        return redirect()->route('auth.login')->with('success', 'Anda berhasil keluar.');
    }
}
```

resources\views\auth\login.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.auth')

@push('style')
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/auth/login.css') }}">
@endpush

@section('content')

<div class="w-100">

    <main class="form-signin w-100 m-auto">
        <form method="POST" action="{{ route('auth.login') }}" id="login-form">
            <h1 class="h3 mb-3 fw-normal">Silahkan masuk untuk absensi</h1>

            <div class="form-floating">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="floatingInputEmail" name="UserID"
                    placeholder="User ID">
                <label for="floatingInputEmail">User ID</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-floating">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="floatingPassword" name="password"
                    placeholder="Password">
                <label for="floatingPassword">Password</label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-check mb-3">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="remember" id="flexCheckRemember">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckRemember">
                    Ingatkan Saya di Perangkat ini
                </label>
            </div>

            <button class="w-100 btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="login-form-button">Masuk</button>
            <p class="mt-5 mb-3 text-muted">&copy; 2022</p>
        </form>
    </main>

</div>
@endsection

@push('script')
<script type="module" src="{{ asset('js/auth/login.js') }}"></script>
@endpush
```

config\auth.php

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Defaults
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default authentication "guard" and password
    | reset options for your application. You may change these defaults
    | as required, but they're a perfect start for most applications.
    |
    */

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Guards
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Next, you may define every authentication guard for your application.
    | Of course, a great default configuration has been defined for you
    | here which uses session storage and the Eloquent user provider.
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | Supported: "session"
    |
    */

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | User Providers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
    | sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
    | be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
    |
    | Supported: "database", "eloquent"
    |
    */

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\Visuser::class,
        ],

        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Resetting Passwords
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may specify multiple password reset configurations if you have more
    | than one user table or model in the application and you want to have
    | separate password reset settings based on the specific user types.
    |
    | The expire time is the number of minutes that each reset token will be
    | considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
    | they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
    |
    */

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Password Confirmation Timeout
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may define the amount of seconds before a password confirmation
    | times out and the user is prompted to re-enter their password via the
    | confirmation screen. By default, the timeout lasts for three hours.
    |
    */

    'password_timeout' => 10800,

];
```

app\Models\Visuser.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Visuser extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory;

    const USER_ROLE_ID = 5;

    protected $fillable = [
        'UserID',
        'password',
        'level',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
    ];

    public function isUser()
    {
        return $this->role_id === self::USER_ROLE_ID;
    }
}
```

app\Models\User.php

```
<?php

// namespace App\Models;

// use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
// use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
// use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
// use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
// use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;

// class User extends Authenticatable
// {
//     use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

//     const ADMIN_ROLE_ID = 1;
//     const OPERATOR_ROLE_ID = 2;
//     const USER_ROLE_ID = 3;

//     /**
//      * The attributes that are mass assignable.
//      *
//      * @var array<int, string>
//      */
//     protected $fillable = [
//         'name',
//         'department',
//         'email',
//         'password',
//         'role_id',
//         'position_id',
//         'phone',
//     ];

//     /**
//      * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
//      *
//      * @var array<int, string>
//      */
//     protected $hidden = [
//         'password',
//         'remember_token',
//     ];

//     /**
//      * The attributes that should be cast.
//      *
//      * @var array<string, string>
//      */
//     protected $casts = [
//         'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
//     ];

//     public function role()
//     {
//         return $this->belongsTo(Role::class);
//     }

//     public function position()
//     {
//         return $this->belongsTo(Position::class);
//     }

//     public function scopeOnlyEmployees($query)
//     {
//         return $query->where('role_id', self::USER_ROLE_ID);
//     }

//     public function isAdmin()
//     {
//         return $this->role_id === self::ADMIN_ROLE_ID;
//     }

//     public function isOperator()
//     {
//         return $this->role_id === self::OPERATOR_ROLE_ID;
//     }

//     public function isUser()
//     {
//         return $this->role_id === self::USER_ROLE_ID;
//     }
// }
```

app\Http\Requests\LoginRequests\LoginRequest.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests\LoginRequests;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Http\Exceptions\HttpResponseException;

class LoginRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array<string, mixed>
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'UserID' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required',
        ];
    }

    public function failedValidation(Validator $validator)
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(response()->json([
            'success'   => false,
            'erorr' => true,
            'message'   => 'Validation errors',
            'errors'      => $validator->errors()
        ])->setStatusCode(422));
    }
}
```

app\Http\Middleware\Authenticate.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate as Middleware;

class Authenticate extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * Get the path the user should be redirected to when they are not authenticated.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return string|null
     */
    protected function redirectTo($request)
    {
        if (!$request->expectsJson()) {
            return route('auth.login');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add your middleware ?

Comment: I have updated above.

Comment: How about the role middleware ?

Comment: I don't know where it is. Can you tell me where it usually is?

Comment: Where did you get the `middleware('role:admin')` ?